# Why does ethanol have a stronger cooling effect on the body than water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

Why does ethanol have a stronger cooling effect than water (i.e. it feels cooler when dropped onto one’s hands) even though water has a higher heat of vaporization compared to ethanol?

If we drop a unit amount of both ethanol and water on two body surfaces (both at same temperature), which substance will lower the temperature of the surface more after complete evaporation?

Comment: You beg the question: What do you mean by "more cooling effect"? More cal/g? Quicker action at room temperature or at body temperature? Without details, it's meaningless. Edit the question with more specific info.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Related: [Why does hand sanitizer leave your skin feeling cool?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15885/81509)